# Check if a list is sorted

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I found this simple solution which checks if a list is sorted.

```
myArray.every((val, i, arr) => !i || (val >= arr[i - 1]));
```

What does `!i` means in this context?

Comment: Did you look up what the second argument of the `every` callback is?

Comment: Yes, I know it's the index number. But I couldn't figure out what's the purpose of the "false" index number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To checks if a list is sorted from the code `myArray.every((val, i, arr) => !i || (val >= arr[i - 1]));` you expect `!i || (val >= arr[i - 1])` to return `true` value.

If you did not use `!i` then for the array index `0` you will get `arr[i - 1]` as `undefined` which will lead to `val >= arr[i - 1]` as `false` which should be `true` in actual case. Thus, to prevent that we use `!i` by which we get `true` when we do `!i || (val >= arr[i - 1])` as `!i` for `0` value will be `true` and `(val >= arr[i - 1])` will be `false` so `true || false` will give you true.

Thus to make the logic work properly you need that check.

Here is a sample example of that:

**With !i**

```js
var a = [1];
var i =0;
var res = !i || (10 >= a[i - 1])
console.log(res);
```

**Without !i**

```js
var a = [1];
var i =0;
var res = (10 >= a[i - 1]);
//hence the every fails and we cannot check further
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Perspicuous answear! Thank you!

Comment: @SimonT.N. glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

`!i` returns for the first element a `true` value, because the check behind works only for index `1` and greater, because of the subtraction for the previous element.

```
!i || val >= arr[i - 1]
^^                       index 0           returns true
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  index 1 ... n - 1 checks condition
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if i = 0, !i = true
if i = 1, !i = false
```

If `i = 0`, there are no value for `arr[i - 1]`.
`!i` returns true for `0th` element.
And for other element, returns `val >= arr[i - 1]`

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful.